# Storing sensor data and dumping event file on Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, text-files, android-sensors

I have written an Android 7 application for storing sensor data of my smartphone in a SQLite database. For example, for the accelerometer I'm getting the values as follows:

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        long timeNano = System.nanoTime();
        long timeMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Save to database
}
```

As can be seen, at every call of `onSensorChanged` (i.e. when a new sensor value arrives), I also retrieve and store the current timestamp in milliseconds and nanoseconds. I think retrieving these timestamps always takes some time (tens of milliseconds). I have a pretty high sampling rate of the sensors.

Is it a problem when I retrieve the timestamp for every sensor value I get? My worry is just that I add artificial delays (queuing) to the sensor values in the case that sensor values arrives faster than retrieving the millisecond and nanosecond timestamp takes.

Second, I also want to dump the `/dev/input/event7` file (on a rooted phone). I can either store it directly in a database (as with the sensor data) or I can just dump it to a text file.

Which one is the better option and is there a possibility that the text file can get corrupted (e.g. when it is not properly closed at the end or when there is a write error)? I think database is safe and should always be in a consistent state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SENSOR_DELAY_UI` = 60,000 microseconds = 60,0 milliseconds delay.

We cannot be certain about the speed of fetching timestamps.
On expensive devices, maybe this takes 10 milliseconds. On cheap devices, maybe 100 milliseconds.

Also, storing the data in a database/file adds a great lot of milliseconds, and so does booting a new thread to offshore this process.

A quick reminder: do not forget that the delay you specify is **only a suggested delay**, so delay can be lower than specified delay. [Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int))

So: it might be not a problem on your superfast ultraphone to fetch these timestamps, as it is fast enough to allow for getting timestamp and store it in a database/file, but it might be a problem on other, slower phones.

You will get gaps in your readings. If one call to `onSensorChanged()` takes e.g. 10 seconds, and every 50 microsecs the function is the specified delay, then there will be a call between every 10 seconds and every 10 seconds plus 50 microsecs.

You can accept the fact that you sometimes have to "skip" a `onSensorChanged()` call. To lower the chances of this occuring, you could specify a larger delay. You can specify a custom delay time in microseconds with 
 `mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, 1000*1000);`

On your second question:
I don't know much about rooted phones, but I know about files.

Reading out /dev/input/event7 and storing it in a database will probably take longer than quickly write content to some text file, if this is still about being fast.

Corruption of a textfile is going to happen if you have 2 write operations writing to 1 file simultaniously. You should always close your first outputstream before opening your second. Commonly, When catching write errors, always close outputstream. Doing these 2 things make sure there is no file corruption.

It is generaly true that writing to a database is safer than writing to a text file, as databases are designed to handle multiple writes, potentially dangerous writes etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can onSensorChanged() not be called several times at the same time? I think that if for example onSensorChanged() needs 10s to finish operation but onSensorChanged() gets called every 50ms, then a lot of method calls happens at the same time. Is this not true?

Comment: I am almost sure that, in your example, 1 call to onSensorChanged() is done (which takes 10s to complete). 50ms later, there will be no calls to onSensorchanged(), as the program is busy with the first call still, and hasn't returned to the android system function callin onSensorChanged. In short: No method calls until 10s have finished

Comment: I've tested it. You are right. Do you think a good alternative would be to create a new thread for each call of onSensorChanged() and then handling the retrieval of the milliseconds and nanoseconds timestamp and the storage in the thread? This has the disadvantage that possibly a lot of threads are created.

Comment: I am afraid that that strategy would indeed keep on creating more threads than it closes per time unit (e.g. one minute). This would lead to a problem where the amount of threads keeps on growing (until Android OS has to jump in or the phone crashes. You want to avoid both).

Comment: Now what I did found out: apparently a SensorEvent has a timestamp in nanoseconds which you can get, by doing ```long nanosecs = mEvent.timestamp;```. This means you don't have to get time from system, which saves time in your function.

Comment: Also, databases in PHP offer prepared statements, where the whole database gets ready to accept ≥1 statements of the exact same type. This might also be available in android! Maybe your database implementation supports this too. That way, your database does not need to prepare every time you want to push.

Comment: There is no way to get rid of this problem entirely, as there "always is a slower phone". Yet, it can be reduced as far as possible by reducing time consumption (less time needed), and give some more time (more time = larger chances of being done within limit and no trouble). In the end, it does not really matter if there is a very very old slow phone somewhere who cannot handle it if it works just fine on almost all phones worldwide, right?